# How to correctly handle nested generic types in Typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, types, nested

I am working on adding types for APIs. I used `axios` to handle the http request. `Axios` enhanced the response and add a lot of infomations there. Our backend response also add some operational information to it. It has data parts and status part as well. Now if I want to correctly typed my api responses, I need to nest one generic type in another. I kindly handle it but it has a `Promise<AxiosResponse<IApiResponse<RealData>>>` format which appears nested together. Is this the right way to handle typing?

Here is an example I have tried and worked

```js
export const getHealth = (): Promise<
  AxiosResponse<IApiResonseData<Health>>
> => axios.get("/HealthStatus");

export interface AxiosResponse<T = any>  {
  data: T;
  status: number;
  statusText: string;
  headers: any;
  config: AxiosRequestConfig;
  request?: any;
}

interface IApiResonseData<T = any> {
  result: T;
  status: IApiGenericStatus;
}

interface IApiGenericStatus {
  code: number;
  description: string;
  text: "SUCCESS";
  severity: "NORMAL";
}

interface Health{
// whatever types it has 
}
```

Is this the right way to handle this kind of generic types nesting?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but if you don't expect the generic type parameters to change much, you can declare a type, like:                                                                  type Response<T> = Promise<AxiosResponse<IApiResponseData<T>>>;                 ... then use it normally, like so:                                                                                                                export const getHealth = (): Response<Health> => axios.get("/HealthStatus");

Comment: Also, in the type definition files for axios, there is AxiosPromise<T> which combines Promise and AxiosResponse. That should reduce the amount of nesting for you.

Comment: @Wingnod Wow, thank you Wingnod. Combining both comments seems the neatest solution for me. Reducing the nesting and provide clean `api.ts` file

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful.